# Write SQL query to create output dataset with quarterly exchange rate based on input table with exchange rate by monthly

Tags: query

from_currency   month   year     exchange_rate

GBP              1      2023    0.7952

GBP              2      2023    0.7738

GBP              3      2023    0.7934

GBP              1      2024    0.8031

GBP              2      2024    0.7938

GBP              3      2024    0.805

CNY              1      2023    0.7952

CNY              2      2023    0.7738

CNY              3      2023    0.7934

CNY              4      2023    0.8031

CNY              5      2023    0.7938

CNY              6      2023    0.8031

Ouput:

from_currency   Quarter year    exchange_rate

GBP     Q1      2023             0.787466667

GBP     Q1      2024             0.800633333

CNY     Q1      2023             0.787466667

CNY     Q2      2023             0.8

Need to write SQL query to create the above output table based on input dataset. The output dataset exchange rate is calculated based on sum of respected month values divided by 3.

Comment: `GROUP BY year, ((month - 1) DIV 3)`